# While reading a csv file i am getting a parser error , when given in list it is giving the same error what should I do to avoid the error

Tags: python, pandas

This is the code:

```
pd.read_csv('https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/blob/master/datasets.csv',skiprows=[69,88],header=None)
```

I am getting following error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 69, saw 2
```

I have tried skipping the rows
When giving individual skiprow value it works for one , but when given in list (rows to skip) it shows the above error.

Comment: which dataset are you trying to get from that link?

Comment: Currently the link given contains html data, as someone already provided solution with raw data alternative way of read_csv would be[`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) as that link is providing html data. something like `tables = pd.read_html('https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/blob/master/datasets.csv')` and then `df = tables[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is when you are fetching it using this url, you are getting the web page and not csv. To get csv click on the raw button which is there and then use that url. Use the below and you'd get it correctly.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/master/datasets.csv')
data.head()
```